# AVERAGEIFS/SUMIFS formula is not sorting ASC or DESC

Tags: excel, sorting, calculated-columns

I am having trouble sorting an AVERAGEIFS column (and a SUMIFS column) DESC or ASC

ESSENTIALLY, I am looking at labor statistics data for 2017-2020; by industry, and year

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!F:F,Data!B:B,E4,Data!A:A,$C$16)
```

Is the formula.
The formula is correct, and yielding the correct values.
However, when trying to sort the values, it does not nothing and just refresh the exact values.

I've connected a chart to the results, which works well, however, I can't organize the bars descending since the source data is having the issue I referenced.
I tried deleting the page references like some other forums suggested to no avail.

Any insight??

[image]

I tried deleting the page references like some other forums suggested to no avail,

I've used dynamic arrays for the industry and plain values to see...

** UPDATE** attaching a photo on what fixed it, thanks so much for everyone contributing!  See second photo for answer

[image]

Comment: Are you sorting columns E with the results in G?

Comment: Your data should get sorted unless you have any dynamic arrays used for the other criteria's means column E

Comment: I am trying to sort the values in G DESC or ASC

Comment: It will not work certainly you need to select column `E` to `G` as well. Then do the sorting based on column `G`

Comment: ok, I have some traction here, when HIGHLIGHTING E, G, the columns sort, but ALPHABETICALLY, what am I missing for it to sort based on the dollar amount average

Comment: no no, Select Columns From `E` To `G` and then sort it

Comment: I got it guys , the shortcut buttons for sort were not working, HOWEVER, I was able to use the SORT BOX next to those buttons after highlighting the selection, and clarify which column to sort. 

THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the chart source data as a whole table and then sort with the sort dialog found in the Data ribbon. However, if the Industry labels are generated with a Dynamic array formula, using `Unique()` for example, then you cannot use a manual sort on the table. You can copy and paste/values the Industry labels, so they are no longer a dynamica array, then sort the table.

[image]

If you need a more dynamic solution, consider using a Pivot Table instead of a formulaic table. What you want to achieve can be done in a Pivot Table / Pivot Chart with just a few clicks, without writing any formulas.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.